# LESS: Target a parent element if it exists

Tags: css, less

So I have a box:

```
<div class="box">Box</div>
```

And sometimes this box may be wrapped in an a tag:

```
<a href="#"><div class="box">Box in an A tag</div></a>
```

Is there a way in LESS to specifically target A tags that are parents of `.box`?

e.g.

```
a {
   color: red;
}

a [that is a parent of .box] {
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: If there is in LESS, you can't select parent element in CSS. So you can't apply css to parent

Answer (score 6):

[No, you cannot select ancestor elements using LESS or CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), but LESS has what is called the [parent selector](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature), or `&`.

> The & operator represents the parent selectors of a nested rule and is most commonly used when applying a modifying class or pseudo-class to an existing selector

So, in your case, instead of changing the `color` of the parent, you could use `&` to target instances of `.box` that have an `a` parent, e.g.

```
.box {
  color: red;

  a & {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

This translates to:

```
.box {
  color: red;
}
a .box {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: What is there are more deeply nested structures such as there are great-grandparent where `div`s are nested inside of `span` element where `span` element is nested inside of `div` element? How do you target those using LESS?
Thank you in advance.