# How to target parent HTML element from deeply nested HTML element using LESS?

Tags: html, css, less

Is it possible to target outer ("great-grand-")"Parent" HTML elements in LESS files where there are `div` elements nested inside of `span` elements interchangeably?

For example:

```
<div class="parent1 class1 class2">Parent shape
  <span class="parent2">
    <div class="parent3">      
      <div class="parent4 some-other-class">
         Some content.... 
      </div>
    </div> 

  </span>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is to apply styling for FIRST `div` element which has  "`.parent1 class1 class2`" classes when most deeply nested `div` element has these classes "`.parent4 some-other-class`"  applied to it.

IMPORTANT NOTES:

1. By default MOST deeply nested `div` element has only `.parent4` class applied to it
2. Styling should be applied to top-PARENT `div` element which has following `parent1 class1 class2` classes applied to it
3. Styling for TOP-PARENT `div` element should be applied IF AND ONLY IF `some-other-class` class is appended to most deeply nested DIV (i.e. when it's `<div class="parent4 some-other-class">`)

This is what I have in `.less` file for now:

```
.parent1{
  &.class1.class2{
    div.parent.some-other-class & div.parent3 & span.parent2 {
      //css styling applied for `div.parent1.class1.class2`
    }
  }
}
```

...but it's NOT working. BTW, ALL selectors must be inside of `.parent1` class in LESS file -> that means .less file  must be like this:

```
.parent1{
   // ALL other selectors (e.g. `.parent2` , `.parent4.some-other-class` ) are inside of this block!
}
```

...and NOT like this:

```
.parent1{
  /* styling */
}

.parent4.some-other-class{
  /* styling */
}
```

[This is most similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37731906/6805866) related to this question, but it's for most trivial case where there is single parent and single child element.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Subarto I've updated my question, please take a look. Thank you in advance.